# laravel 5.4 Request::session() should not be called statically

Tags: laravel-5.4

I am using Laravel 5.4,
I rewrite the `validator()` method of `RegisterController` out of the box,as follow:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class RegisterController extends Controller
{

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        $validationCode = Request::session()->get('validation_code', '');
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'role' => 'required|in:1,2',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
            'validation_code' => 'required|in:' . $validationCode
        ]);
    }

}
```

There is an error:

```
Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::session() should not be called statically
```

Why is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$validationCode = Request::session()->get('validation_code', '');
```

to this:

```
$validationCode = session()->get('validation_code', '');
//or
$validationCode = request()->session()->get('validation_code', '');
//or
$validationCode = Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::session()->get('validation_code', '');
//or
$validationCode = \Request::session()->get('validation_code', '');
```

`Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request` and `Illuminate\Http\Request` are two different class, the first is the facade the second the actual request class. My advice is to use the helper function `request()` you will have less confusion.